# Changing .htaccess code to fit my website structure

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess code:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/angular2-sens>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /angular2-sens
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /angular2-sens/index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

Now, this code is from some tutorial I found - and I need to change it to fit my webstie structure.

My website is located in `mydomain.com/v2`

and the directory is `/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/v2/`

Hope you can help me with this.

I tried to do it myself and failed - returned error 500. (Place .htaccess in the v2 folder)

```
 <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </Directory>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your `/v2/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v2/

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

`<Directory>` directive is not allowed in `.htaccess`.